# Reading data from MySQL by modifying built-in functions

Tags: mysql, sql, c, r

I know that there are many functions in R to read external data and build internal vectors and matrices. For example, read.table, read.csv, read.fwf, etc. These functions allow you to read flat file data to build vectors and matrices. I also know that there are a few packages which allow users to interface R to MySQL but having gone through them, I was not impressed with the manner in which they handle the data. It appeared to be inefficient but for staticians who are not familiar with C programming, it is a good choice.

I am admittedly a novice in R but had used S years ago so am somewhat familiar with it more as a user. I think that it would be easy to adapt the built-in functions for file handling to get data from MySQL using MySQL's C-interface (ODBC drivers or whatever C-interface it provides).

Questions:

1. Are the above functions written in C? I have not gone through the Rsource code.
2. Has this already been done. In other words, am I reinventing the wheel here?
3. Is there a better choice? Is my approach flawed?

Comment: (1) You haven't provided any details about why you "aren't impressed" with RODBC or RMySQL, so it would be hard for anyone to comment on what would be an improvement. (2) Am I reading you right that you are suggesting to modify a function like `read.table` to retrieve data from a MySQL db?

Comment: RMySQL has about 5000 lines of C + about 1500 of R.  RODBC is about 1500 lines of C + about 1500 of R and its operation substantially depends on the actual ODBC driver you use.  There is also the JDBC interface package RJDBC which is about 1000 lines of R and java code and whose operation would substantially depend on the particular JDBC driver used.

Comment: @Thomas. Yes, I want to modify read.table to create a function to read from MySQL. I find that RMySQL is bloated FOR WHAT I WANT. I want to primarily use the graphics functionality of R with integer, double-precision, boolean, character (rarely) and date/time datatypes. Date/time are read as character strings in RMySQL which is very inefficient if I want to do any meaningful time series analysis. Also, I see security issues in the absence of any support for prepared SQL. I admit that my conclusions are based upon cursory reading but the implementation I am thinking of should be simple.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck You seem to be very familiar with R internals. Am I off track?

Comment: On my laptop I can convert a character vector 10,000 long to POSIXct in a bit over 1 second.  If we store the datetimes as seconds since the Epoch then it takes 0.01 seconds to convert a vector that long to POSIXct.  You might want to first consider whether you really need the features you mention and if you conclude that you do then first investigate how much work it would be to add them to RMySQL.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck Very useful info. Thanks.